# CGAL partitioning of polygon-with-holes

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal, convex-polygon

I'm looking at the Partition_2 section of the manual and examples to see if CGAL can handle convex partitioning of a polygon with holes.  All of the examples appear to use Polygons without any holes.  Does anyone know if this is supported by any of the CGAL partitioning algorithms?

https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Partition_2/include/CGAL/partition_2.h

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/index.html

Thanks,
Josh.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> **All the partitioning functions** present the same interface to the user.
> That is, the user provides a pair of input iterators, first and
> beyond, an output iterator result, and a traits class traits. The
> points in the range [first, beyond) are assumed to define a **simple**
> polygon whose vertices are in counterclockwise order.

[Simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20simple%20polygon%20%2F%20%CB%88%20p,joined%20pairwise%20to%20form%20a%20single%20closed%20path.) means no holes and no self intersection.

Handling polygons with holes is not hard to achieve since CGAL also provides [boolean operations on polygons](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Regularized_Boolean_Set-Operations). Just create the partition and subtract the holes. This may not be an ideal solution if your use case is performance critical (directly partitioning a polygon with holes can be faster).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to suggest an alternative.  I'll give it a shot and see how it works, but I don't think it will give me quite what I am after.  I'm trying to build a navigation mesh which captures the interior of the polygon-with-holes as a mesh of convex polygons.  I suspect that the method you're suggesting will result in non-convex polygons in some cases, or will result in what I'll call badly conditioned convex polygons...  They might be a mesh, but not a good one for navigating.  Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

Right, the "2D Polygon Partitioning" package supports only polygons without holes (as far as I know). You can always triangulate a polygon with holes using the edges (on the outer and inner CCBs) as constraints. Another option is to use vertical decomposition. It is directly provided by the "2D Minkowski Sums" package; see [Polygon_vertical_decomposition_2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__vertical__decomposition__2.html). It is based on the decompose(arr, oi) free function that accepts as input a 2D arrangement; see [CGAL::decompose()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/group__PkgArrangementOnSurface2Funcs.html#gae20b2917f6de15db9bf025f83abf8e89). The output is a collection of pseudo trapezoids (a pseudo trapezoid can be a triangle in degenerate cases), so it's a bit "better" than pure triangles and extremely efficient, especially if you have the underlying arrangement at hand.